# Authenticating ActionCable connections

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

I've found a wonderful ActionCable gem, which is a good solution for SPA.

I want to send only the `html`, `css` and `js` assets, all other connections will be implemented through `ActionCable`. It's not difficult to exchange strings or integers, but how can I login through ActionCable?

Comment: Login has to be done using usual Rails way,  you can check whether user is authenticated as explained here: https://github.com/rails/actioncable

Comment: I know that I can do this, but I need all site working through the websockets. Can I implement this?

Answer (score -8, accepted):

The solution is to use HTTP authorization token. It's simple, widespread and obvious. [This article](https://auth0.com/blog/2015/04/09/adding-authentication-to-your-react-flux-app/) helped me a lot

Answer (score 6):

From the [Readme](https://github.com/rails/actioncable/blob/02238/README.md#a-full-stack-example)

```
# app/channels/application_cable/connection.rb
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    identified_by :current_user

    def connect
      self.current_user = find_verified_user
    end

    protected
      def find_verified_user
        if current_user = User.find(cookies.signed[:user_id])
          current_user
        else
          reject_unauthorized_connection
        end
      end
  end
end
```

So it looks like you could insert your own `find_verified_user` logic here. The `reject_unauthorized_connection` method lives in `lib/action_cable/connection/authorization.rb` for reference.

From [Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/websocket-security#authentication-authorization):

> [authentication] can be done in a variety of ways, as WebSockets will
>   pass through standard HTTP headers commonly used for authentication.
>   This means you could use the same authentication mechanism you’re
>   using for your web views on WebSocket connections as well.
>
> Since you cannot customize WebSocket headers from JavaScript, you’re limited to
>   the “implicit” auth (i.e. Basic or cookies) that’s sent from the
>   browser. Further, it’s common to have the server that handles
>   WebSockets be completely separate from the one handling “normal” HTTP
>   requests. This can make shared authorization headers difficult or
>   impossible.

With this in mind it would likely be a real pain not to just use a normal web login flow to set your auth cookie, delivering your SPA after the authentication step, but hopefully this can give you some pointers.

Answer (score 6):

FYI, if you have `devise` already installed in your application, then you can use the environment variable set by `warden` to find the `authenticated user`. For every authenticated user warden stores the user object in environment var. Every request is authenticated by `warden` middleware.

**Note**: this [env](http://rack.github.io/) is different from `ENV`.

```
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    identified_by :current_user

    def connect
      self.current_user = find_verified_user_from_env
    end

    private
    def find_verified_user_from_env
      # extracting `user` from environment var
      current_user = env['warden'].user
      if current_user
        current_user
      else
        reject_unauthorized_connection
      end
    end
  end
end
```

---

If you have not used `devise` then, here is another solution. Precondition is, you will have to set a signed cookie called `user_id` in your `sessions_controller` or something like that.
eg

```
cookies.signed[:user_id] = current_user.id
```

and for connection:

```
# app/channels/application_cable/connection.rb
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    identified_by :current_user

    def connect
      self.current_user = find_verified_user_from_cookies
    end

    private
    def find_verified_user_from_cookies
      current_user = User.find_by_id(cookies.signed[:user_id])
      if current_user
        current_user
      else
        reject_unauthorized_connection
      end
    end
  end
end
```